# Does anyone know how to get JACK effects working in Manjaro?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, manjaro, jack

I've been trying to get `zita-at1` to work with discord calls for a while, to allow for autotune shenanigans.

I've installed the JACK and Cadence packages and upon opening up Cadence, it shows the error message: `jackdbus is not available` and does not allow me to advance any further.

I'm using PulseAudio for all my main audio stuff and PulseEffects for all my audio effects, but it's quite limited, and I want to move to JACK, which has much more support for plugins.

If possible, I want to keep using PulseAudio for my main audio interface and JACK for plugins and effects.

Edit: Do not have QjackCTL installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have QjackCTL installed? I would go about removing that first for cadence to work properly. Cadence and QjackCTL will combat each other.
Ref: [Manjaro Forums - jackdbus is not available](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/jackdbus-is-not-available-cadence/119837)

Also, the Arch Wiki is very well documented on Jack and Pulse.

Have a look at these links:

- [Jack Audio Connection Kit (Arch Wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit)
- [Sound System (Arch Wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sound_system)

Comment: I've managed to get audio out from Cadence now, but I cannot output audio to my Bluetooth headphones from within Cadence. It only uses my laptop's inbuilt speakers, even when plugging in some speakers via the 3.5mm socket. Edit: I don't have qjackctl installed at all.

Comment: @PrintStringName What is your output of `jackd`

Comment: here's the output of command `jackd` https://imgur.com/Ff6ynEJ.png

Comment: Seems like that was jackdmp?

Comment: would it be helpful to see any other configuration menus? like the pulseaudio menu or the JACK menu

Comment: Yes @PrintStringName. Put it in OP.